# Are the logarithms of the integer polynomials discrete in $L^1$ of the unit circle?

Tags: nt.number-theory, fa.functional-analysis, polynomials

Tautologically, the integer polynomials form a discrete set in $L^1$ of the unit circle. On the other hand, a set of logarithms ordered by norm becomes generally rather denser than the original set.

*Is the set
$$
\big\{ \log{|P|} \, : \, P \in \mathbb{Z}[X] \setminus \{0\} \big\} \subset L^1(\mathbb{T})
$$
of functions on the complex unit circle $\mathbb{T} = \{ z \mid |z| = 1 \}$ discrete in $L^1$, or does it have an accumulation point?*

I am equally happy with the $L^2$ norm, if it makes a difference.

Comment: I don't quite understand your first remark - could you elaborate? Probably I am just being slow and missing something

Comment: @Yemonchoi if $P(z)=\sum c_n z^n$, then $\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} P(e^{it})e^{-ikt} dt=c_k$. Thus $\|P\|_{L^1}\geqslant \max_k |c_k|$ and the distance between two distinct integer polynomials is not less than $1$.

Comment: Thanks @FedorPetrov - indeed I was just being slow

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is still discrete though not uniformly. Since $\log|P|=\frac 12\log|p|$ where $p=P\bar P$ is a real non-negative trigonometric polynomial with integer coefficients, it is enough to work with $p$ instead of $P$. We have
$$
|\log p-\log q|\ge \frac{|p-q|}{\max(p,q)}.
$$
Now consider the outer function $f$ with $|f|=\frac 1{\max(p,q)}$, so 
$$
|f(0)| = \exp\Big(-\int_{\mathbb T}\log{\max(p,q)}\Big)  \ge  \exp\Big(-\int_{\mathbb T}[|\log p|+|\log q|]\Big).
$$
Then, denoting by $r$ the difference $p-q$ multiplied by an appropriate power of $z$ so that $r(0)\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$ and $r$ is analytic, we get
$$
\int_{\mathbb T}|\log p-\log q|\ge \int_{\mathbb T}\frac{|p-q|}{\max(p,q)}
=\int_{\mathbb T}|r||f|\ge |r(0)||f(0)| \\ \ge \exp\Big(-\int_{\mathbb T}[|\log p|+|\log q|]\Big)\,,
$$
finishing the story.

Comment: Really nice! Your inequality doesn't need that $P,Q$ have integer coefficients, but only that $\big| \|P\|_{L^2}^2 - \| Q\|_{L^2}^2 \big| \geq 1$ if it is not zero. Here is another consequence of applying this remark to $Q = 1$. For every complex polynomial $P = \sum_{i=0}^d a_iz^i$ of degree $d \geq 2$ and with non-zero free term, there is a positive constant lower bound on the Mignotte height $\widetilde{h}(P / \sqrt{|a_0a_d|}) := \int_{\mathrm{T}} \frac{\log^+ |P|}{\sqrt{|a_0a_d|}} > 0.1$ (that appears in the Amoroso-Mignotte refinement of the Erdos-Turan equidistribution theorem).

Comment: One outstanding question here is whether or not the discreteness should be uniform if we restrict to the subset of the integer polynomials $P \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ with a bound $M(P) \leq T$ on their Mahler measure.

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov 1) I'm not so sure: I need the geometric mean in the story (the condition you wrote is way off what you really meant, so I'm trying to answer the implied question) 2) Yeah, one has to think a bit more in this case. I have no time now, but you've seen all my tricks by this time :-)

Comment: 1) Oh, but of course $p(z)−q(z)$ is not analytic at $z=0$, and it was absolutely crucial that $r(z)=z^m(p(z)−q(z))$ was a polynomial in $z$ and not in $z,z−1$... I see. Ah well, but that only makes this proof more interesting! 2) I don't think this is nearly so easy: a positive constant lower bound by a positive function of $m(P)+m(Q)$ instead. But I do know it at least for small enough Mahler measures.

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov 2) It is not so hard either. Note that either $\int|\log p-\log q|\ge 1$, or $\int \log\max(p,q)\le 1+\int\log p=1+2M(P)$, after which the same bounds work. You can optimize this dichotomy a bit, of course.

Comment: Ah! But of course, your lower bound is really by $\exp(-\int \log{\max(p,q)})$ and not merely by the final $\exp(-\int (|\log{p}| + |\log{q}|))$ of your answer... This is great and it answers all my issues - thanks very much! Just to point out my initial observation for small enough Mahler measures: $\| \log{|P|} - \log{|Q|}  \|_{L^1} + m(P) + m(Q)$ turns out equal to none other than twice the Mahler measure of the bivariate asymmetric polynomial $wQ(z) - P(z)$, which is bounded away from zero by Breusch-Smyth (if $P/Q$ does not preserve the unit circle).

Comment: And one further comment, although less interesting. Your proof was based on the Poisson kernel, but it ultimately comes down to the elementary inequality of your first display. The generalization to multivariate Laurent polynomials is trivial from here, for $r$ commuting variables. That makes me curious about the hypothetical non-commutative generalization as in this paper of Deninger http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2006-19-03/S0894-0347-06-00519-4/S0894-0347-06-00519-4.pdf (cf. section 3 on the functional calculus defining $\log(ff^*)$, for $f \in \mathbb{Z}[\Gamma] \setminus \{0\}$).

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov OK, OK, one thing a time ;-) If you get stuck again on some lemma, feel free to post it and, perhaps, I'll think of it, but I'd rather abstain from diving too deep into all this stuff now. :lol:

Comment: Just saying where my question came up: from the observation with $m(wQ(z) - P(z))$. Your bound is much better, as it applies to all $T$ - thanks! Whereas the 'further generalization' ...was just for the sake of pointing out one :-). A side note which, as I wrote, is less interesting than the above.